# How to get transaction history in Corda?

Tags: corda

To get state I can use Vault, but what about transactions? How I can get them, for example, by txHash? Is it possible to do this by CordaRPCOps, there is `internalVerifiedTransactionsSnapshot` method, but it is deprecated now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, note that as of Corda 3, there are no stability guarantees regarding the behaviour of any method to retrieve a transaction or its dependencies. In particular, we cannot guarantee that the set of transactions retrieved will not change across Corda versions.

This is because in future versions of Corda, nodes will likely only exchange transaction chains in SGX-encrypted form. These transaction chains will then be verified inside an SGX enclave on the node. This will prevent nodes from seeing the contents of the transactions they are verifying (see the blogpost here: https://www.corda.net/2017/06/corda-sgx-privacy-update/). This may even go so far as to only allow nodes to see certain parts of the transactions they are signing.

**Ways to retrieve transactions as of Corda 3**

**1. Using `CordaRPCOps.internalVerifiedTransactionsSnapshot`**

If you are interacting with the node via RPC, `CordaRPCOps.internalVerifiedTransactionsSnapshot` returns a list of all recorded transactions.

If you only wanted to get a single transaction and you knew its hash, you could write:

```
val transactions = cordaRPCOps.internalVerifiedTransactionsSnapshot()
val signedTransaction = transactions
    .find { it.id == transactionHash }
    ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown transaction hash.")
```

Note that the transactions returned are of type `SignedTransaction`. This form does not contain the transaction's attachments or inputs (only the attachment hashes and input state references).

To retrieve a transaction's attachments via RPC, you could write:

```
val transactions = cordaRPCOps.internalVerifiedTransactionsSnapshot()
val signedTransaction = transactions
        .find { it.id == transactionHash }
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown transaction hash.")

val attachmentHashes = signedTransaction.tx.attachments
val attachmentStreams = attachmentHashes.map { hash -> cordaRPCOps.openAttachment(hash) }
```

And to retrieve a transaction's inputs via RPC, you could write:

```
val transactions = cordaRPCOps.internalVerifiedTransactionsSnapshot()
val signedTransaction = transactions
        .find { it.id == transactionHash }
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown transaction hash.")

val inputStateRefs = signedTransaction.inputs
val inputStates = inputStateRefs.map { stateRef ->
    val transaction = transactions.find { it.id == stateRef.txhash }
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown transaction hash.")
    transaction.tx.outputStates[stateRef.index]
}
```

**2. Using the `ServiceHub`**

If you are in a situation where you have access to the node's `ServiceHub` (e.g. within a flow or a Corda service), you can use `serviceHub.validatedTransactions.track().snapshot` to get all transactions, and `serviceHub.validatedTransactions.getTransaction(transactionHash)` to get a specific transaction by hash.

Note that the transactions returned are of type `SignedTransaction`. This form does not contain the transaction's attachments or inputs (only the attachment hashes and input state references).

To convert the `SignedTransaction` to a `LedgerTransaction` (where the attachments and inputs are resolved), you could write:

```
val signedTransaction = serviceHub.validatedTransactions.getTransaction(transactionHash)
val ledgerTransaction = signedTransaction.toLedgerTransaction(serviceHub)
```

**3. By connecting to the node's database**

You can connect directly to the SQL database backing the node, and retrieve the transactions using an SQL query.

Comment: If I am using ServiceHub method, then i am getting an error. Change return type to List<SignedTransaction>

Answer (score 1):

That's right, although please note that the ServiceHub and SQL approaches are basically the same thing as the deprecated RPC and may also stop working in future (or not, depending on how we manage the transition to an encrypted ledger).

There are other approaches you can use. For instance you could aggregate the bits of history you care about up into the latest version of the state. This also lets you restrict the view of the history once SGX lands.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution (Using CordaRPCOps.internalVerifiedTransactionsSnapshot) is really slow.

It is exist one more way to get transaction history and it is pretty effective.

You can do it by using rpcOps.vaultQueryBy

```
fun transaction(transactionId: String): List<Vault.Page<ContractState>> {
    // get jdbc connection (you may simplify it within cordapp) 
    val jt = jt()
    // get all states of transaction
    val output_indexes = jt.queryForList("SELECT OUTPUT_INDEX FROM VAULT_STATES WHERE transaction_id = '$transactionId'", Int::class.java)
    val transactionHash = SecureHash.parse(transactionId)
    // get Rpc connection
    val rpcOps = initialiseNodeRPCConnection()
    val transactionStates = output_indexes.map {
        val constraintTypeCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(status = Vault.StateStatus.ALL, stateRefs = listOf(StateRef(transactionHash, it)))
        rpcOps.vaultQueryBy<ContractState>(constraintTypeCriteria)            
    }
    return transactionStates
}
```