# How do we track Cash State in Corda

Tags: corda

For example we have 3 Nodes Say

1. Party A
2. Party B
3. Party C

Consider these transactions

1. Party A Self issues 10 USD
2. Party A transfers 10 USD to Party B
3. Party B transfers 10 USD to Party C

So my question is can Party c know that this 10 USD is came from Party A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Party C knows that this 10 USD came from Party A. Party C automatically resolves the chain of transactions back to transaction `1` when receiving transaction three.

This allows Party C to ensure that the entire chain of transactions is valid, and not just the latest transaction.

In the future, [the use of SGX](https://docs.corda.net/head/design/sgx-integration/design.html) will likely allow parties to verify an entire transaction chain without seeing the contents of each transaction. So Party C would not see that Party A issued the original cash.

Corda also allows each owner in the transaction chain to choose to identify themselves using an anonymous, one-time-use public key instead of a well-known identity. Thus someone walking the chain will not see who the past owners were.

Comment: Can Party C view all the previous owners of the state if there is multiple transactions before trnx 3?

Comment: Currently, yes. This is required, for example, to check that the owner signed the transfer at each stage. Hiding this is the intent of SGX. However, Corda also has the ability for each owner in the chain to choose to identify themselves using an anonymous, one-time-use public key instead of a well-known identity. Thus someone walking the chain will not see who the past owners were.

Comment: so how do i get the previous owners of this cash state?

Comment: You'd have to look at the historic transactions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594282/how-to-get-transaction-history-in-corda/50602322#50602322.