# Whats the best way to generate ledger change Events that include the Transaction Command?

Tags: corda

The goal is to generate events on every participating node when a state is changed that includes the business action that caused the change. In our case, Business Action maps to the Transaction command and provides the business intent or what the user is doing in business terms. So in our case, where we are modelling the lifecycle of a loan, an action might be to "Close" the loan.

We model Event at a state level as follows: Each Event encapsulates a Transaction Command and is uniquely identified by a (TxnHash, OutputIndex) and a created/consumed status.

We would prefer a polling mechanism to generate events on demand, but an asynch approach to generate events on ledger changes would be acceptable. Either way our challenge is in getting the Command from the Transaction. 
We considered querying the States using the Vault Query API vaultQueryBy() for the polling solution (or vaultTrackBy() for the asynch Obvservalble Stream solution). We were able to create a flow that gets the txn for a state.  This had to be done in a flow, as Corda deprecated the function that would have allowed us to do this in our Springboot client. In the client we use vaultQueryBy() to get a list of States. Then we call a flow that iterates over the states, gets txHash from each StateRef and then calls serviceHub.validatedTransactions.getTransaction(txHash) to get signedTransaction from which we can ultimately retrieve the Command. **Is this the best or recommended approach?**

Alternatively, we have also thought of generating events of the Transaction by querying for transactions and then building the Event for each input and output state in the transaction. **If we go this route what's the best way to query transactions from the vault?** Is there an Observable Stream-based option?

I assume this mapping of states to command is a common requirement for observers of the ledger because it is standard to drive contract logic off the transaction command and quite natural to have the command map to the user intent.

**What is the best way to generate events that encapsulate the transaction command for each state created or consumed on the ledger?**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're attempting to get a notified when certain types of ledger updates occur (open, approved, closed, etc).

First: Asynchronous notifications are best practice in Corda, polling should be avoided due to the added weight it puts on the node for constant querying and delays. Corda provides several mechanisms for Observables which you can use: https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.messaging/-corda-r-p-c-ops/vault-track-by.html

Second: Avoid querying transactions from the database as these are intended to be internal to the node. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50602322/935979) for background on why to avoid transaction querying. In general only tables that begin with "VAULT_*" are intended to be queried.

One way to solve your use case would be a "status" field which reflects the command that was used to produce the current state. For example: if a "Close" command was used to produce the state it's status field could be "closed". This way you could use the above vaultTrackBy to look at each state's status field and infer the action that occured.

Comment: Thanks Austin. We have, in fact, implemented the solution you suggest. We have extended our state classes to include the transaction command and any other transaction-level info that we need. We do this on output states whenever we build the transaction and then use Observables with vaultTrackBy to capture the events on participant nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to finish up on my comment: While the approach met the requirements, The problem with this solution is that we have to add and maintain our own code across all relevant states to capture transaction-level information that is already tracked by the platform. I would think a better solution would be for the platform to provide consumers access to transaction-level information (selectively perhaps) just as it does for states. After all, the transaction is, in part, a business/functional construct that is meaningful at the client application level. For example, If I am "transferring" a loan, that may be a complex business transaction that involves many input and output states and may be an important  construct/notion for the client application to manage.