# Corda: How can I know all the info about a specific Transaction?

Tags: hash, transactions, sdk, rpc, corda

I'm new to Corda and I already listed all the signed transactions but now I'm trying to list all the info about a specific transaction (by hash) with the RPC.

Can anybody tell me if it's possible and if it is how can I do that?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Run this command with your Transaction ID in node CRaSH shell

```
run internalFindVerifiedTransaction txnId: <Transaction-ID>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. But that method returns a SignedTransaction and that class doesn't have what I need... I need to get the details about the transactions, the ones that are on the Token and not just the ID and the notary. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: Check this link to get the data of a transaction in a programmatic way [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594282/how-to-get-transaction-history-in-corda]

Answer (score 0):

```
    // proxy is returned by the rpc connection   

 FlowProgressHandle<SignedTransaction> flowHandle = proxy
            .startTrackedFlowDynamic(YourFlowName.class,
                    Param1,param2
            );

    progressTrackerService.getProgressTracker(flowHandle, request);


    // The line below blocks and waits for the flow to return.
    final SignedTransaction result = flowHandle
            .getReturnValue()
            .get();


    //suppose I want to get ABCState outputState  from the above txn
    // Like wise you can do any type of filtering on the returned Txn

    List<ABCState> aBCStates= result.getTx().outputsOfType
    (ABCState.Class);
```