# How to get transaction history of an account on corda

Tags: corda

I know how to get all transactions of a node via this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50602322/12623949). But I can not figure out how to select by account. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Starting Corda 4.3, `VaultQueryCriteria` has a new attribute `externalIds` to query by account: https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/docs.md#querying-the-vault-by-account

Comment: Adel Rustum, thank you, this query only gets states, not transactions, right? I need transactions

Comment: Adel Rustum, by the way, do you know how to add token criteria to the above query? Thank you

Comment: `QueryUtilities.kt` from the `Tokens SDK` has lots of useful functions; check it out.

Comment: As for transactions, I don't know how to get them by account.

Comment: Adel Rustum, do you have any ideas? I really need how to do :(

Comment: or do you know how to get token transfer history between accounts?

Comment: I followed this example (https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/flow-db) to create a custom table that stores my token transactions (i.e. issue, transfer, redeem); so every time I do one of those commands, I insert a record in my custom table (which has columns such as from, to, quantity, timestamp, etc...).